# cannot change background, no files on desktop

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I have installed Gnome Desktop (`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`) recently after that I cannot change wallpaper of Ubuntu desktop and also I cannot see any files on desktop.
I am on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: This may sound strange, but try and start `nautilus`. Don't use a terminal.

Comment: @ByteCommander I am using nautilus, it is working fine

Comment: So it solved the question? It seems that a part of nautilus that stays active in the background as daemon is responsible for the desktop icons and probably more. So whenever I see no desktop icons, I try to restart Nautilus as a first step. And usually that helps. If it helped you too, please tell me and I'll write it as answer. Your last comment is not totally clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since after installation of Gnome Desktop I had this problem, I have removed Gnome Desktop

```
sudo aptitude purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo systemctl reboot
```